# PyRun_File and PyImport_Import not compatible while embedding Py into C++

Tags: python, c++, python-embedding

I am making a C++ app with embedded Python.
I use *PyImport_Import *to import module and *PyObject_GetAttrString* to import function from it.
The problem is that if .py file was imported with *PyImport_Import * I cannot use same .py file.

Here is code example

```
void call_module_func(std::string module_name, std::string func_name)
{
    auto pName = PyUnicode_DecodeFSDefault(module_name.c_str());
    auto pModule = PyImport_Import(pName);
    auto pArgs = PyTuple_New();
    auto result = PyObject_CallObject(pFunc, pArgs);

    //DecREFS...
}

void run_file_main(std::string file_name)
{
    auto globals= PyModule_GetDict();
    auto locals= PyDict_New();
    auto fp = fopen(file_name.c_str(), "fb");
    PyDict_SetItemString(globals, "__name__", PyUnicode_FromString("__main__"))
    auto result = PyRun_File(fp, file_name.c_str(), Py_file_input, globals, locals);
    //DecREFS and close...
}
```

now with these two functions I can call my_file.py

```
def main():
    print("Hello world")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("you are main")
    main()
```

If I use C++ functions like this

```
run_file_main("my_file.py");
call_module_func("my_file", "main");
```

my output is as expected:
"you are main"
"Hello world"
"Hello world"

If I switch C++ functions like this

```
call_module_func("my_file", "main");
run_file_main("my_file.py");
```

my output is not as expected:
"Hello world"

As I understand after PyImport_Import doing its job I can reload it. But it looks like I need to unload module.
Another solution would be to call Py_Finalize and then Py_Initialize, but it is bugged and calling these function several times brings errors.

So can anyone help how to solver such problem - importing python file as module, unloading it and then running same module as file?

I tried to embed Python module into C++ program and run it as imported module and as file with arguments. But depending on sequence of calls results vary, while I expected them to be the same